# LaTeX: Balanced twocolumn Text with Footnotes only in the right column (ftnright)

Tags: footnotes, two-column, multicol

Do the packages `ftnright` and `balance` work together?

I'm looking for a solution to generate a twocolumn text in LaTeX. My footnotes should appear at the bottom of the right column. However, my main problem is the last page: Both columns should be balanced and the footnotes should be placed right under the text. As a result the last line of the left column should be next to the last footnote.

I tried to archive this with the following code. Unfortunately, if the last page is less than half filled, the last footnotes will appear on another empty page.

Does anyone has an idea how to fix this?

My code that generates [this pdf-file](http://f.cl.ly/items/0b3M093m0f1g0E3o263X/ftnright-balance-test.pdf).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{ftnright}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\balance

\blindtext \footnote {First Footnote}

\blindtext \blindtext \footnote {Another Footnote}

\blindtext \footnote {Third Text}

\blindtext  \blindtext

\blindtext \blindtext \footnote {Problematic Footnote appears on page 3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that neither `balance` nor `multicol` will work together with `ftnright` out of the box as all packages assume the standard LaTeX output routine in place so that they can modify it.

In theory such things could coexist but in case of balancing it is not quite clear what the expected behavior should be (especially in case of `multicol` this is a bit problematical as you could have several balanced blocks or different numbers of columns (which is why the standard approach for `multicol` is to make footnote page-wide).

Making the `balance`package `ftnright` aware is probably easier, but still would be a large rewrite of the package.